Hide specific buttons under page name and show only for Admin
enter image description here
Need to show only "edit with Elementor" to "Author" user role
or if there is any method to manage this section
I want to hide or show this buttons by user role
i have many user roles with different permissions so i need this user role only to edit this page with elementor

You only want to show the 'edit with Elementor' option for authors when hovering a page in the Wordpress pages screen. You can do that with the following code;
function modify_page_row_actions($actions, $post) {
    // Check if current user is an author
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $allowed_roles = array('author');

    if (array_intersect($allowed_roles, $current_user->roles)) {
        // Keep only Elementor edit link if it exists
        if (isset($actions['edit_with_elementor'])) {
            return array(
                'edit_with_elementor' => $actions['edit_with_elementor']
            );
        }
    }
    return $actions;
}

// Apply to pages
add_filter('page_row_actions', 'modify_page_row_actions', 99, 2);
// Apply to posts if needed
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'modify_page_row_actions', 99, 2);

This will remove all actions except the 'edit with Elementor'. Does this solve you're issue?

This code hide Elementor permanently from the admin menu bar and dosnt effect the list under page name row..
I want to KEEP "Edit with Elementor" and hide other choices "Edit | Quick Edit | View "

@AgmaarCompanyConsultation-T Thank you for the additional explanation; i've updated my answer; does that help you?
